# How to access QObject::sender in a C++ lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, qt5

This is a rather unusual problem - but a problem nonetheless. I have a function that accepts a lambda as a parameter and then passes it on to `QObject::connect`:

```
template<typename Functor>
void MyClass::doSomething(Functor f)
{
    connect(network_reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, f);
    //...
}
```

A sample invocation of `MyClass::doSomething` might look like this:

```
doSomething([]()
{
    // how do I get access to the sender???
});
```

As you can tell by my comment, there is no way to access `QObject::sender` to get a pointer to the `QObject` that emitted the signal. Because the class emitting the signal is not in the scope that the lambda is being created in, there is no way of referencing it inside the lambda.

What options do I have?

---

**Edit:** I tried using Andy's suggestion (`std::bind`) but I end up getting one of those template errors that are nearly impossible to understand:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1614425/

Excerpt:

```
decltype cannot resolve address of overloaded function
```

...and it points to the `QObject::connect` call.

Comment: Are you trying to make the lambda receive a pointer to a `MyClass` object?

Comment: It needs a pointer to the `QNetworkReply` that exists in `MyClass::doSomething`.

Comment: By "exists in `MyClass::doSomething`" you mean it is an object local to that function? Or is it a member variable of `MyClass`?

Comment: @AndyProwl: It exists in `MyClass::doSomething`. It is not a member variable.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison: I tried a solution, but I'm not sure I understood correctly your requirements. I did not post it as a comment because of formatting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood your requirements correctly, you can first let your lambda functor accept an argument of the appropriate type (passing by reference here, so take care of lifetime issues):

```
doSomething([](QNetworkReply* p)
{
    // Here you have the sender referenced by p
});
```

Then, your `doSomething()` template function could use `std::bind()` to make sure your lambda will be invoked with the appropriate object as its argument:

```
template<typename Functor>
void MyClass::doSomething(Functor f)
{
    connect(network_reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, bind(f, network_reply));
    //...
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you. This also avoids the `dynamic_cast<>` I would have had to perform with `QObject::sender`.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison: Forgot one little detail: when binding, you should use `ref(...)`, or the argument will be passed by value.

Comment: That's okay - `network_reply` is actually a `QNetworkReply *` so passing by value isn't a problem.

Comment: I think I spoke too soon - I get an error that `decltype cannot resolve address of overloaded function` and it's pointing to `QObject::connect`.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison: what is the signature of `connect`? Have you adapted the lambda so that it takes a pointer, if `network_reply` is of type `QNetworkReply*`?

Comment: `connect` is overloaded but the only overload that accepts three parameters looks like this: `static QMetaObject::Connection connect(const QObject *sender, PointerToMemberFunction signal, Functor functor);`.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison: That's strange. I'm no Qt expert unfortunately. What is the signature of acceptable `Functor`s?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea... I've poured over the Qt source code and I can't seem to figure out exactly what's going on. Also, I tried casting the return value of `std::bind` to type `Functor` but the compiler doesn't like that either, calling it an "invalid cast".

Comment: @GeorgeEdison: And when you passed a lambda that takes no argument, did that compile?

Comment: Nope - that didn't compile either. I get the `decltype` error in that case.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison: Then the premise of the question was wrong, I've assumed it did compile. Not sure if you should not open another question asking about the proper way of calling `connect`, and adapt this answer accordingly. I believe this answer does provide a solution to your question, at least design-wise.

Comment: Yes, your solution does and I will mark it as accepted. I'll open a new question for getting `std::bind` working with `QObject::connect`.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison: Actually, if you say the lambda without arguments can't be passed as a `Functor` either, I don't think `std::bind` matters at all. It's mostly about figuring out what's the correct signature of a `Functor`. But honestly I would expect a reference manual to tell that

Comment: I **finally** figured it out and got something to compile. I needed to wrap the return value of `std::bind` in an `std::function`. So I end up with something like this: `std::function<void()> func = std::bind(f, network_reply)`. Then I pass `func` to `connect`.